# Configuration of network incorrect

Tags: c#, tensorflow, keras

I'm a novice to Keras and Tensorflow. I am unsuccessfully trying to reshape [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation) for Python (which I'm not familiar with at all); I have formulated the following code fragment.

```
var Functions = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var BatchSize = 64;
var InputDim = Functions.Count();
var OutputDim = 256;
var RnnUnits = 1024;

var iLayer1
  = new Embedding(InputDim,
                  OutputDim,
                  input_shape: new Shape(new int[] { BatchSize, 0 } ) );
var iLayer2
  = new GRU(RnnUnits,
            return_sequences: true,
            stateful: true, recurrent_initializer: "glorot_uniform");
var iLayer3 = new Dense(InputDim);

var iSequential = new Sequential();
iSequential.Add(iLayer1);
iSequential.Add(iLayer2);
iSequential.Add(iLayer3);
```

While this compiles, I'm getting the error message

```
Python.Runtime.PythonException:
"ValueError : Input 0 is incompatible with layer gru_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4"
```

when

```
iSequential.Add(iLayer2);
```

is executed. To my superficial understanding, this means that `iLayer1` is configured in a way that makes it impossible to operate it together with `iLayer2`, but I have no idea what to do.

Edit: After some messing around, I got the error message

```
ValueError : slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of
bounds. for 'gru_1/strided_slice_10' (op: 'StridedSlice') with
input shapes: [0,64,256], [1], [1], [1] and with
computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If C# Keras uses the same convetions as Python Keras, your input shape for the embedding should not include the batch size.

Since you are forced to use the batch size due to `stateful: true`, you need to use the `batch_input_shape` argument istead of `input_shape`.

I'm not sure about `0` there. Is this the C# convention for variable length?

The error is saying that the second layer got a 4D tensor from the previous layer, while that tensor should have been 3D.

Options:

- `batch_input_shape: new Shape(new int[] { BatchSize, 0 } )`
- `batch_shape: new Shape(new int[] { BatchSize, 0 } )`
- `input_shape: new Shape(new int[] { 0 } ), batch_size: BatchSize`

If none of these work on C#, you will have to try the functional API model instead of the sequential model.

Comment: Keras.NET does not have an agument called `batch_input_shape` if I'm not mistaken; I'm totally new to this.

Comment: It should have, try it. If it fails, try `batch_shape`. If it also fails, try `input_shape: new Shape(new int[]{0}))` and `batch_size: BatchSize`.

Comment: The parameters are `input_dim`, `output_dim`, `embeddings_initializer`, `embeddings_regularizer`, `activity_regularizer`, `embeddings_constraint`,`mask_zero`, `input_length`, `input_shape`.

Comment: I don't know how C# does it, but these shape parameters are not from the layer, they're probably extension or superclass parameters. So, did you get a compilation error when you tried? -- I added a few options to the answer. If none of them work, then you will probably need to try the functional API model.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not parameter `batch_size`; the interface is strongly typed so I cannot pass the parameter at a best try.

Comment: Functional API, then, the `Input()` function/class should have a `batch_shape` argument that belongs to it.

Comment: Or you could try to think the problem differently and use `stateful: false`. Then the batch size would not be necessary. The vast majority of the problems I see don't need `stateful: true`. This is only for cases where your data can't fit into the memory due to its "length in steps" (not number of samples) or when you want to predict future steps from future steps.

Comment: I used to be a C# programmer, but I moved to Python because of neural networks. Today I prefer Python, the only thing that makes me go back to C# is either creating executable files or operating applications via their .NET interops.

Comment: Thanks for your very kind help; I'm currently messing around with Keras, my only tools being a PhD in CS, 10 years of industry experience and a 20 minute YouTube video about neural networks.